# Prove that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I can already see that the $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n}$ converges by graphing it on Desmos, but I have no idea how to algebraically prove that with L’Hopital’s rule or induction. Where could I even start with something like this?

Edit: For context, I came across this limit while studying the series expansion for the Lambert W Function, $W(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}x^n}{n!}$ . By the ratio test, it is clear that $|x|<\frac1e$ in order to converge, but I needed to use the Alternating Series Test to see whether this series converges at $x= \pm\frac1e$. Finding $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}|a_n|$ is the first step of the test.

Comment: Do you know Stirling's approximation ?

Comment: Yes, actually. I didn’t think to start there!

Comment: The question is: what tools are you allowed to use? If Stirling's approximation is assumed to be known, the  problem is done.

Comment: If we replaced $e$ by any other constant the ratio test would be conclusive, but precisely for $e$ we get that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ tends to $1$ so that fancier tricks are needed. I think this question was asked here many times in slightly different forms (e,g, $n^n$ in the numerator, or the numerator and denominator swapped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the simple fact that

$$e^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{k!} \stackrel{k=n}{>} \frac{n^n}{n!}$$

Hence, you get

$$0<\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n} < \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!\frac{n^n}{n!}} = \frac 1n$$

Answer (score 1):

First of, note that from the A-G inequality one gets $(1+1/(n+1))^{n+1} > (1+/1/n)^n$
In words, that the sequence $a_n = (1+1/n)^n$ is increasing. One can see this by substituting $b_1=1$ and  $b_k = 1+ 1/n$, k = 2,3,...n+1 in A-G inequality.
Of course $a_n$ tends to $e$ so each term is less than $e$.
Now, let $c_n = \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n}$.
The ratio $c_{n+1}/c_n$ is equal to $(1+1/n)^{n-1}*\frac{1}{e} = (1+1/n)^n*\frac{1}{1+1/n}*\frac{1}{e}$.
But $(1+1/n)^n < e$ so $c_{n+1}/c_n < \frac{1}{1 + 1/n} = \frac{n}{n+1}$.
If you multiply these inequalities side by side from n down to 1 you get that
$c_{n+1} < \frac{1}{n+1}$ so the sequence tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Stirling approximation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation,
$$ n!> \sqrt{2\pi n}\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n e^{\frac1{12n+1}}$$
one has
$$0<\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n} < \frac{n^{n-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac1{12n+1}}e^n} < \frac 1{n}.$$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

Taking the logarithm, you need the limit of

$$(n-1)\log n-\sum_{k=1}^n\log n-n.$$

Then the summation can be estimated by an integral and the second term is

$$\sim n(\log n-1).$$

A more precise bounding of the integral will lead to a formal proof.